# Datasheet GPS Microsoft Band

Tags: microsoft-band

I want to develop a software and in the next month hardware for receive Microsoft Band data, specifically from GPS, but I need the datasheet or fabricant of Band's GPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to find some of that information in a teardown or fix guide.

eg [This one](https://www.sparkfun.com/news/1681) or [this one](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Microsoft_Band)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be more specific about the information you want when you say "datasheet or fabricant of Band's GPS" but, in any case, the current Band SDK (v1.3.10702) does not expose a means of streaming GPS sensor data from the Band.

Comment: I know that the official SDK doesn't expose of GPS data, but I want to know the reference of GPS module used by Microsoft in Band or something like that for browse the datasheet.

Comment: I don't believe Microsoft has publicly released detailed specifications for individual sensors on the Band.